# Best practices for Cordova/Ionic Plugins management?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

What are the best practices for checking in plugins for my Ionic/Cordova project?

I would like to minimize the number of files that are checked into my project. Mainly I do not want to checkin any file that my project downloads from an outside source and also want to leave out any files generated with my build command.

The hope is to checkout my project and then run `ionic platform add <platform> ;ionic build <platform>` and be good to go.

I'm not sure how to implement in the root `config.xml` file or in a `plugins/<platform>.json` file

I've also tried using the `hooks/after_platform_add/010_install_plugins.js`, so far this seems to be the best option.

Any tips would be much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bad idea to do it in the hooks. Here is an example along that idea: http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/24/managing-cordova-plugins-with-package-dot-json-and-hooks/

Comment: I implemented this so that I have all my plugins listed in my package.json and an after_platform_add hook to load the packages and install them. Works great!

Comment: Perfect! Maybe do a pull request with this addition!!